# AngularJS global variable not accessible in a module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, global

In my AngularJS project I've got a global variable that contains some data: the domain name and image directory. I need this variable in some views. Here is how the variable looks like and how it is set:

**config.js**

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
   var conf = angular.module('stormforsStats.config', ['ngRoute']);

   //SET GENERAL VARIABLES
   conf.value('SERVER_DATA', {
     'BASE_URL': '/',
     'IMG_URL': 'assets/src',
     'API_URL': '../api/'
   });
   conf.value('APP_DATA', {
     'APP_NAME': 'Stormfors Stats',
     'APP_VERSION': '0.1'
   });

   conf.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'index.html',
          controller: 'ConfCtrl'
      }).otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
      });
   }]);

   conf.controller('ConfCtrl', ['$log', '$location', 'SERVER_DATA', function ConfCtrl($log, $location, SERVER_DATA) {
        SERVER_DATA.BASE_URL = $location.absUrl().substring(0, $location.absUrl().length - $location.url().length).replace("#","");
        SERVER_DATA.IMG_URL = SERVER_DATA.BASE_URL + SERVER_DATA.IMG_URL;
   }]);
})();
```

I already successfully injected the global variable, into one of my other modules like this: 
**header.js**

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  var header = angular.module('stormforsStats.header', []);

  header.directive("headerBar", [function(){
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      templateUrl: "header/header.html",
      controller: 'HeaderCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'header'
    };
  }]);

  header.controller('HeaderCtrl', ['$log', '$scope', '$location', 'SERVER_DATA', function($log, $scope, $location, SERVER_DATA){
    $log.log('header controller initialized');
    this.imgUrl = SERVER_DATA.IMG_URL;
    this.baseUrl = SERVER_DATA.BASE_URL;
  }]);
})();
```

In this module I successfully access the variable in the module's template. When I try this in another template, notifications, this also works: 
**notifications.js**

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  var notifications = angular.module('stormforsStats.notifications', ['ngRoute'])

  notifications.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/notifications', {
      templateUrl: 'parts/pages/notifications/notifications.html',
      controller: 'NotificationsCtrl'
    });
  }])

  notifications.controller('NotificationsCtrl', ['$log', 'SERVER_DATA', function($log, SERVER_DATA) {
    this.imgUrl = SERVER_DATA.IMG_URL;
    this.baseUrl = SERVER_DATA.BASE_URL;
    $log.log('notifications controller: '+this.baseUrl);
    $log.log(SERVER_DATA);
  }]);
})();
```

The code above successfully logs the variable.

No problem so far, but when I try to inject the variable into a very similar module, it doesn't work. Even when I type a typo in the injections, it doesn't get detected, although the controller is executed and the log in the controller shows: 
**home.js**

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  var home = angular.module('stormforsStats.home',['ngRoute', 'stormforsStats.factory'])

  home.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'home'
    });
  }])

  home.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$log', 'dataFactory', 'SERVER_DATA', function($rootScope, $scope, $log, dataFactory, SERVER_DATA) {
    this.imgUrl = SERVER_DATA.IMG_URL;
    this.baseUrl = SERVER_DATA.BASE_URL;
    $log.log('home controller: '+this.baseUrl);
    $log.log(SERVER_DATA);
  }]);
})();
```

The home.js code does log 'home controller' but nothing about the injected variable.
Could anyone help me with this problem, or put me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Btw I tried to remove all the injections from home.js so that the code is pretty much the same as notifications.js but even then the problem still occurs.

Comment: I think you should be using a service rather than module for holding your config information. Read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Answer (score 0):

```
var home = angular.module('stormforsStats.home')
```

initiates a different module than the module that you initiate with

```
var conf = angular.module('stormforsStats.conf').
```

You also didn't add stormforStats.conf to the dependencies of stormforsStats.home so you can't use something that your module doesn't recognises.
Add the dependency and it'll be solved
( this should solve it:
 `var home = angular.module('stormforsStats.home',['ngRoute', 'stormforsStats.factory', 'stormforsStats.config'])` )

Comment: I just tried it, and no this doesn't solve it. If this would be true, why can I access the variable without explicitly injecting 'stormforsStats.config' in the two other modules I mentioned? I had read that using .value() will set your variable accessible for the whole app. Isn't that right?

Answer (score 0):

when your stormforsStats.home module depends on your stormforsStats.config module, then enumerate it in the module declaration

```
var home = angular.module('stormforsStats.home',['ngRoute', 'stormforsStats.factory', 'stormforsStats.config'])
```

Comment: Hi. The problem isn't solved by injecting the config module. I would also like to ask, how come in the 2 other modules the variable is accessible without explicitly injecting the config module?

Comment: what is the order of the script tags in your HTML?

Comment: <script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="config/config.js"></script>
<script src="datafactory/datafactory.js"></script>
<script src="header/header.js"></script>
<script src="parts/pages/home/home.js"></script>
<script src="parts/pages/notifications/notifications.js"></script>